# SQL find specific nodes and return their values (json) as excel formatted results

Tags: sql, json, excel, xml, parsing

There is a xml column (ArrayOfString) with json string results. I need to find specific nodes and get their value.

```
<ArrayOfstring xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
    <string>
        [report_submit_1, {
        "total": 14,
        "report": [
                {
                "date": "11/02/2018",
                etc...
                },
                {
                "date": "01/02/2019",
                etc...
                },
                {
                "date": "12/12/2018",
                etc...
                },
                etc...
            ]
        }]
    </string>
    <string>
        [something_else, {
        "total": 1,
        "report": [
                {
                "date": "12/15/2018",
                etc...
                },
                {
                "date": "03/25/2019",
                etc...
                },
                {
                "date": "04/12/2019",
                etc...
                },
                etc...
                ]
        }]
    </string>
    <string>
        [report_submit_2, {
        "total": 22,
        "report": [
                {
                "date": "05/22/2019",
                etc...
                },
                {
                "date": "01/02/2019",
                etc...
                },
                {
                "date": "12/12/2018",
                etc...
                },
                etc...
                ]
        }]
    </string>
</ArrayOfstring>
```

```
SELECT 
Xml.value('(.[1])', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') AS Results
FROM tableA 
WHERE Xml.exist('(/ns:ArrayOfString/ns:string[contains(.,"report_submit")])') = 0
```

Would like this 'parsed' as xls style in sql results, so it can be saved off as an excel file with headers

Comment: Are you using MS SQL Server and its T-SQL?

Comment: Sorry... It's for SQL Server. The Json data contains a bunch of different node names, I'd like to find all the ones that contain the report_submit within the node name and get the full Json data value for those nodes. Parsed out so the results can be saved in Excel format